# How to add a single image to a cylinder

Tags: texturing

I want to know how to apply a single image, like so

[image: so],

to a primitive cylinder. I tried using the node editor with this chain:

Texture Coordinate - Mapping - Image texture - diffuse - output

but I don't think it works at all.

Any help?

Comment: Are you trying to apply it in top and bottom faces, whole cylinder with top and bottom faces or only the body?

Comment: have you unwrapped your cylinder?